# Encrypt section of app.config

Tags: c#

I have this app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
                    <security>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="myServiceAddress"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="LARGE VALUE" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

How can I encrypt the `system.servicemodel` section so nobody can see my endpoint or whats the name of my service interface? I already tried this solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows but it doesnt seem to work when I set the `sectionName` parameter to `configuration`.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If you think you need to hide your endpoint, you're doing web services wrong. Implement authentication, as anyone with access to the server or network it runs on can monitor the traffic and find out the endpoint and the messages being exchanged.

Comment: I've got to agree with @CodeCaster on that right there. But if you do find a need for encryption that isn't security by obfuscation, this is the best blog post I've ever found on it. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Comment: I would like if possible to encrypt from the very first section of the app.config file, the `config` section. But `ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);` is always null when `sectionName = config`